# QGIS rule-based using symbol size and color at the same time

Tags: qgis, symbology

I'm trying to apply a rule-based approach to my data that considers both the positive or negative value and the value per se (from -66 to 77). I was able to apply a rule for negatives/positives (red and green, respectively), but how can I add the rule for symbol size considering the size of the number? (e.g., a value of 10 would have a bigger point symbol size than a value of 5).

What I did so far:

```
negative: "diff" < 0 (single red color)
positive: "diff" > 0 (single green color)
neutral: "diff" = 0 (single purple color)
```

I'm trying to do this for a point vector (I can't upload an image here; the server is bugged)

Comment: What kind of vector data are we talking about?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit with more information

Comment: @Erik Ok, I added more info. Unfortunately, I cannot add a screenshot. StackExchange is not allowing me.

Comment: Have you had a look at [`data-defined override`](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/introduction/general_tools.html?highlight=data%20defined%20override#data-defined-override-setup)?

Comment: I did not. How can I edit it on the `size` option to do what I'm asking? (i.e., bigger values = bigger symbol sizes)

Comment: OK, GOT IT! Thanks for the tip. I'll add the answer to my question

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after @Erik comment I got it pretty easy. All I had to do was to double click each of my point vector labels -> go to Size section -> click on the data defined override -> select `diff` (the column I'll be using for size labeling) and that's it.